# Java Android Studio application, display pdf file within the application

Tags: java, android, pdf

Hello I am writing an application for an hospital that should open a Pdf file(online) with the correct calendar week as presented in my code.

it should display the pdf file right away inside the app, instead of trying to download it from the link or asking to open it with an external android pdf view program.

The app should display, what food is there to buy in the canteen each day, like presented in the uploaded pdf file.

I tried to use classes like PDFRendererBasic but since i am quite new to Android Studio, I did not find out yet, how to implement this into my code so my application works.

Additionally I found out that i can open the pdf file with a code like

```
public class MyPdfViewActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView mWebView=new WebView(MyPdfViewActivity.this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&      url="+LinkToPDF);
    setContentView(mWebView);
  }
}
```

So if anyone could help me to do this/implement this in my application or explain me (best detailed) how to do it it would be great.

This is **my code:**

```
public void MensaEssensplan (View view) {
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.GERMAN);

Date date = calendar.getTime();

int jahresWoche = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

String kw = (String.valueOf(jahresWoche));

//fills algorithm with correct week of year, because each week a new canteen plan is uploaded

String rawLink = "https://intranet.uke.de/dateien/tochtergesellschaften/kge-klinik-gastronomie-eppendorf/ma_kw_"+kw+".pdf";
Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(rawLink));
startActivity(browserIntent);
}

//opens pdf file with correct week of year ending in the pdf link.
```

would be great if someone can tell me how to do this.

Comment: You almost answered your question yourself. What is your particular problem?

Comment: If i implement the code "public class MyPdfViewActivity extends Activity" into my code it firstly marks "mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);"  red: 'Cannot resolve method setpluginsEnabled(boolean)'. When i run the code and open the method with the button, the app crashes "App stopped running".

Comment: Like how do i implement the webview correctly into my code?